# Error trying to move data from Azure table to DataLake store with DataFactory

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I've been building a Datafactory pipeline to move data from my azure table storage to a datalake store, but the tasks fail with an exception that I can't find any information on. The error is

> Copy activity encountered a user error: ErrorCode=UserErrorTabularCopyBehaviorNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=CopyBehavior property is not supported if the source is tabular data source.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'.

I don't know where the problem lies, if in the datasets, the linked services or the pipeline, and can't seem to find any info at all on the error I'm seeing on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the copy behavior from Azure Table Storage to Azure Data Lake Store is not currently supported as a temporary work around you could go from Azure Table Storage to Azure Blob Storage to Azure Data Lake store.

[Azure Table Storage to Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-table-connector/)

[Azure Blob Storage to Azure Data Lake Store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector/)

I know this is not ideal solution but if you are under time constraints, it is just an intermediary step to get the data into the data lake.

HTH

Comment: Is there a timatable for when this is going to be supported? Could I use a custom activity instead?

Comment: You can use a custom activity.  Here is a post I wrote up on how to connect to Azure Data Lake store from a custom acvtivity: http://eatcodelive.com/2016/02/06/accessing-azure-data-lake-store-from-an-azure-data-factory-custom-net-activity/

Comment: this looks great, thanks! A question, could this work for reading from an eventhub instead of a table?

Comment: This might be a better option: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/03/14/integration-with-azure-data-lake-store/

Answer (score 0):

The 'CopyBehaviour' property is not supported for Table storage (which is not a file based store) that you are trying to use as a source in ADF copy activity. That is the reason why you are seeing this error message.